# Knowing the number of threads started by a particular thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In the following program `main` thread calls `startThread` which gets started on a new thread.It calls `greet_thread` which in turn calls `greet` on a new thread. `startThread` calls `greet_thread` till the `count is less than or equal to 10`.

Is there any way I can tell how many threads are currently running ? Being more specific, I want to know the number of threads currently running started by a call to `greet_thread`. As `greet_thread` is called `10 times`,it is obvious that `10 threads`  will be running alone at the end. But is there a way to know the number ?

This is hierarchy of the threads started in the program :

```
main_thread
  | 
 \ /
starts a new thread by calling startThread
  |
 \ /
startThread starts a new thread by calling greet_thread-->--|
  |                                                         |
 \ /                                                       \ / gets called 10 times
 greetThread is started with an infinite loop------<------- |
  |
 \ /
 greet() method is called
```

---

```
class Tester {

    private static  int count = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        startThread();
    }

    public static void startThread() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(count <= 10) {
                    greet_thread(count);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    public static void greet_thread(final int count) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    greet();
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    public static void greet() {
        System.out.println("GREET !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of why you would want to know and how it would be used?  For example, could you not use a counter or a thread pool?

Comment: @PeterLawrey just to check how many threads were running at any instance. There have to be some 30K threads running..There is an exact number.So wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 30K threads running you have a problem.  I suspect you don't have this many CPUs.  You can check the number of threads using VisualVM, or a ThreadGroup or a thread pool, or using a counter.

Usually when you design a program you know how many threads you want and you only need to check this is the case.  You don't deliberately write a program with an unknown, but very high number of threads and try to work out what it is later because this number won't be very useful.

Comment: I agree that 30k thread is to much. But, if you want to monitor your threads programmatically, maybe you can use a class called ThreadMonitor implemented [here](http://kickjava.com/src/ThreadMonitor.java.htm)

Comment: I want to discuss a point with you. Can we please discuss here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27781/discussion-between-peter-lawrey-and-saplingpro

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Is your website vanillajava.blogspot.com down??

Comment: can you suggest something : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27781/discussion-between-peter-lawrey-and-saplingpro ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am total google fan as well but the page goes completely white and blank.. can you double check..

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to count the number of threads that are still alive, then change the `run` method to increment a shared counter when it starts, and decrement it when it terminates (normally or via an exception).

Note you will need to use something like an `AtomicInteger` to implement the counter ... or do something to synchronize the updates.  Incrementing a primitive integer is not atomic, and this can lead to heisenbugs if not adequately synchronized.

(And the same for your existing `count` variable!)

Comment: aah!  can you please give a simple demonstration

Comment: Of what?  Of how to use an AtomicInteger?  You should be able to figure it out by reading the javadocs!  Or this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html